# Does the 2k length limit for URLs on IE still exist for IE 7 and IE 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, url, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Does the 2k length limit for URLs on IE still exist for IE 7 and IE 8?  (the post IE 6 era)

Comment: What is your use case for URLs longer than 2k characters?

Comment: He probably.wants.a.really.really.really.really.really.really.long.com/domain :-)

Comment: @ILMV As a side note, domain names cannot be more than 63 characters (DNS limitation). :)

Comment: there are tons of category_id[] for example, and they becomes category_id%5B%5D -- they are from serialize() of a form's parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

Seems like it still exists, because IE8 is the shipped browser on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

All IE requests go through Wininet.  Have a look at the Win7 SDK header files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include>findstr /spin /c:"INTERNET_MAX" *.h
WinInet.h:85:#define INTERNET_MAX_HOST_NAME_LENGTH   256
WinInet.h:86:#define INTERNET_MAX_USER_NAME_LENGTH   128
WinInet.h:87:#define INTERNET_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH    128
WinInet.h:88:#define INTERNET_MAX_PORT_NUMBER_LENGTH 5           // INTERNET_PORT is unsigned short
WinInet.h:89:#define INTERNET_MAX_PORT_NUMBER_VALUE  65535       // maximum unsigned short value
WinInet.h:90:#define INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH        2048
WinInet.h:91:#define INTERNET_MAX_SCHEME_LENGTH      32          // longest protocol name length
WinInet.h:92:#define INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH         (INTERNET_MAX_SCHEME_LENGTH \
WinInet.h:94:                                        + INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH)
WinInet.h:1712:#define MAX_GOPHER_HOST_NAME        INTERNET_MAX_HOST_NAME_LENGTH
WinInet.h:1720:                                    + INTERNET_MAX_PORT_NUMBER_LENGTH   \
Winineti.h:1511:#define URL_LIMIT INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH
```

So, yes, that length limitation applies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

Answer (score 1):

The length limit for IE7 and IE8 is currently 2083 characters.

If you think you are going to go over this limit, you can use a a frame with a short url and contain the page with the long url inside that frame.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427) it applies to IE7 and IE8:

Answer (score 0):

I have Javascript successfully executing a GET request successfully up to to 4096 characters in Internet Explorer 8. Requests longer than this will execute, but the parameters beyond that length are truncated off. I can't find that documented anywhere, but that's what I've found empirically.

Comment: This is odd. The limitation is there. Could you post the code you used to test?